# javascript/jQuery find all Strings and replace - but

Tags: javascript, jquery

Find all the words and replace - but only the words that are not contained in links.

```
<div class="test">

<br />
<a href="#">TEST</a>
<br />
TEST
</div>

<div class="test">

<br />
<a href="#">TEST</a>
<br />
TEST
</div>
```

Find ALL  "TEST" Only, which do not exist in a link.

Comment: You need to use `contents()` to avoid filtering out DOM `text nodes`. Bet you Arun P Johny posts an answer very soon :)

Comment: replace it with what

Comment: Fixed couple of *my* silly mistakes.. Working version below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contents()` to avoid filtering out DOM text nodes (which jQuery does by default):

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Ln1Lvakc/7/

```
$('.test').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) == "TEST";
}).replaceWith("hello!");
```

notes:

- `nodeType` 3 is a text node
- `$.trim` is a handy jQuery static method to trim strings (as not all browsers have .trim on strings)
- In this particular case you do not actually need the trim, but it depends on whitespace in the HTML